# How can I batch export all bookmarks to Illustrator?

Tags: arcpy, export, bookmarks

My map has about 40 bookmarks. I want to export each to an individual Illustrator file. I've tried to adapt [code I saw elsewhere](https://community.esri.com/thread/94219), but I'm a total python novice. Instead of getting 40 exported files, it's re-exporting the same file name over and over.

```
import arcpy.mapping
Folder = r"H:\My Documents\Maps" 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")  
df= arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers") [0]  

for bkmk in arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd, "", data_frame=df):  
    df.extent = bkmk.extent  
    dfname = bkmk.name  
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()  
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToAI(mxd, Folder + "\map" + dfname + ".ai", resolution=300)
```

Edit November 15, 2017: this code now seems to work, at least once. I'm not sure what problem I had going before; maybe it was related to the output folder. I have found, however, that if something breaks in the script (e.g., one time I had a backslash in a bookmark name) I can't rerun it even after fixing the issue. I have to restart my ArcMap session.

Comment: Perhaps convert them to polygons first, use as data driven pages and try to export.

Comment: @PolyGeo can direct you to code converting bookmarks to polygons. I use his.

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP. I know that's an alternative, but now that I have my bookmarks set I want to use them. I also want to learn why this isn't working for my own knowledge.

Comment: I wonder what file name you've managed to produce? Use r"\map" anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code for a *script tool* I use for such tasks (exporting to PDF), it works just fine. Just adapt the script in order to produce an .ai file. *(more information on how to set up a script tool can be found [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/create-a-python-script-tool.htm))*

There are a few downsides to this method however: you cannot easily switch layers on / off with this script (as mentioned in the comments, using DataDrivenPages is of advantage here); there are certain exporting problems with word / excel objects in your map layout (such as headers); labels can be troublesome for exporting like this; you should not run this tool in background mode, as there might be missing layers in your exported product.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy

workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)


arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
arcpy.env.scratchworkspace = workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

mxdPath = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) # arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
prefix = u"{}".format(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))
postfix = u"{}".format(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3))
desiredresolution = arcpy.GetParameter(4)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdPath)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
bookmarkList = arcpy.mapping.ListBookmarks(mxd, data_frame=df)
arcpy.AddMessage("""{0} bookmarks found. Exporting PDFs...""".format(len(bookmarkList)))
mxd.activeView = "PAGE_LAYOUT"
i = 1
for bookmark in bookmarkList:
    df.extent = bookmark.extent
    outName = u"{0}".format(bookmark.name)
    outFile = u"{0}\{1}{2}{3}".format(workspace, prefix, outName, postfix)
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, outFile, "PAGE_LAYOUT", resolution = desiredresolution)
    arcpy.AddMessage("""Bookmark Nr. {0} exported...""".format(i))
    i += 1
del(mxd)
```